# How should i fetch a random field of a mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, discord, discord.js, mongoose-schema

```
const myschema = new mongoose.schema({
  userID: message.author.id,
  BookesPages: {
    Fallingforyou: {type: Number, default: '685'},
    Intheblack: {type: Number, deafult: '369'}
  },
})
```

this is an example code, how should i increment in any one of them randomly

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of the field names in an array.  Then use a function to randomly generate the number of an index in that array.  Afterwards, you can use the value of the array at that index as the random key you want to access.

Here's an example:

```js
// just using regular object here, since we can't use mongoose on stack overflow
const myschema = {
  userID: "412341234",
  BookesPages: {
    Fallingforyou: {
      type: Number,
      default: '685'
    },
    Intheblack: {
      type: Number,
      deafult: '369'
    }
  },
}

// array of schema keys
const schemaKeys = ['userID', 'BookesPages']

// get a random value from values in an array
const getRandomValue = (array) => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
  
  return array[index]
}

// get random key
const key = getRandomValue(schemaKeys)

// now you can get the value corresponding to the random key in your schema
console.log(myschema[key])
```

This won't work on the subdocuments however, like Fallingforyou or Intheblack.  You'd have to use recursion to get those.